# Freelance as your own Business

Tags: freelance-websites, payments, local-business

How difficult is to freelance not use a website like Upwork or Fiverr and  do it on your own would you have to setup your own website? I plan to be IOS software Developer  with no clients.

Comment: Difficult to answer, as it depends on your line of business, experience and whether you are strarting from scratch with zero clients or already have some connections. Try to make your question more specific.

Comment: The difficulty is not in setting up your website, the difficulty is in getting known and attracting customers. Do not believe SEO companies that will promise to rank you high: they'll just suck your money.

Comment: This, I just edited hope make more sense:)

Comment: What is your strength ?

Comment: What you mean by my strength?

Comment: Mh, you don't even know what they call strength...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is extremely difficult to be an "IOS software Developer with no clients". Clients are the life blood of freelancing.

While some will suggest looking at your strengths, the real question is "what are your weaknesses?"
Freelancing is a business. As such, it needs sales and marketing, accounting and legal help, as well as delivery of goods or services. It is said (by Peter Drucker) that the essentials of a business are innovation and marketing. If you can't sell, you don't have a business. Just putting up a website is likely to wind up as if you only were shouting in a dust storm - getting a dry, dusty mouth.

There are many companies out there that offer X number of potential client contacts per month. These work for some, but for many of us, they just use money and produce contacts that don't generate clients.

Getting paying clients is so difficult for most developers that they wind up working for a sales company such as an existing "contracting company". Another choice is to hire a salesperson or partner with one. A good salesperson can generate enough sales to keep 5-10 developers busy (and are compensated accordingly). In other words, you are now building a business.

Comment: You don't capitalize on your weaknesses, they are too numerous. Only your strengths can help you, especially when starting a business.

Comment: @HarryCover I'm not suggesting to capitalize on weaknesses. Instead, we have to be brutally honest about our weaknesses and get other people who have those areas as strengths (or start training ourselves in those areas). Lack of honesty about our weaknesses is the cause of a many a business failure.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with your advice.

Comment: First I said I  never had client become I was start out with it as a part-time.I try to do some search online before I start one. :)

Comment: @HarryCover Perhaps you are misunderstanding my point. You are correct in emphasizing strengths when dealing with customers. My point is to have brutal honesty _with_ _yourself_ - to know what you can and cannot do and where you need outside help.